# SSRS A-Z bookmarks

Tags: search, filter, reporting-services, bookmarks

I have a lengthy list report that gives individuals surname and first name. It is ordered alphabetically on surname.

Currently the user manually scrolls to find a name. I would like to put 26 buttons at the top of the report and set each one up as a Bookmark to take me to the first surname in the list starting with that letter.

This is only my vision for the report, so if you have done something similar or have an alternative suggestion, I am open to learning.

Many Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There are some different approaches depending on how the report will be utilized. If your users will know the surname to search for all the time, then you can incorporate a parameter for the users search on the surname.

**Example. This basic set up will allow your user to enter any surname (partials too) before the report executes and your result will be filtered based on the surname**

*Parameter setup*

name: surname

prompt: Enter Surname

data type: Text

*Dataset query: *assuming you are using SQL**

```
SELECT surname, firstname
FROM table
WHERE surname  LIKE '%' + @surname + '%'
```

Comment: Thank you. I certainly have some users that I think might prefer to search in this way.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not bothered about how it looks, then the easiest way would be to use a document map.

This is easy to do.

First, add a parent row group as the outermost group. When the dialogue box prompts you to specify a group by expression, click the fx button and use an expression something like...

```
=LEFT(Fields!Surname.Value, 1)
```

Now that your group has been created you can delete the column that is generated (but NOT the group - when prompted).

Now right-click the rowgroup in the groups panel , choose properties, click the advanced tab and set the "Document Map" expression to be the same expression.

Now when you run the report, you will get a list of Letters down the left which will automatically navigate to the start of the respective surnames when clicked.

If you need more help, let me know and I will expand on this answer with images etc.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will definitely give this a try.

Comment: The nice thing is that if you export to excel for example, the links still work correctly (assuming you are not using a really old version of SQL Server)